# Fix console character set in Windows Linux Subsystem's byobu

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, byobu

I have been working with Windows Linux Subsystem for a while but having some minor issues in byobu:

[image: highlighted issues]

I can see the same problem when running bash+byobu from PowerShell, as well as running through alternative terminal application (I have tried ConEmu for example).

Any idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: [AskUbuntu knows this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492802/).

Comment: Aside from the real answer linked by @JdeBP, what happens if you run `export PS1="$"` ?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 WSL, disabling the "Session" part solved the issue, i.e, F9 → Toggle status notification → deselect "Session".